Don't know how to setup luajit for neovim, would appreciate any advice
I'll mention this first: I'm completely unfamiliar with vim, I only have experience with using VSCode for about 3 days, and I am only knowledgeable with the LaTeX programming language, which I was learning within the Overleaf online editor. I am decent with computers when finding a simple fix, but NOT with greatly complex problems such as coding. Please keep this in mind when helping me as there are some pretty basic instructions that I seriously don't understand but am willing to understand with a bit of patience. I have honestly been trying to get Neovim together for about 2 days now and I honestly just wanna get it over with because supposedly Neovim is much better than VSCode, with the speed and comments that people make about it.
What have I done: I took a look at the getting started section of LazyVIm and the following instructions:

Neovim >= 0.9.0 (needs to be built with LuaJIT)

Git >= 2.19.0 (for partial clones support) ✅

a Nerd Font(v3.0 or greater) (optional, but needed to display some icons)

lazygit (optional) ✅

a C compiler for nvim-treesitter. See here

for telescope.nvim (optional) ✅?



live grep: ripgrep ✅




find files: fd ✅


a terminal that support true color and undercurl: ✅



kitty (Linux & Macos)




wezterm (Linux, Macos & Windows)




alacritty (Linux, Macos & Windows)




iterm2 (Macos)



So far, I have downloaded Vim from the MSI installer from GitHub, downloaded Git, lazygit (windows scoop), ripgrep (scoop), fd (scoop), Cygwin, vim plug and alacritty. I should mention that when I install these, I always let the path be what the installer decides, and always just clicked next on the installer instructions on all these software. Probably not the best practice, but I don't want a headache from deciding and want to let the system decide what is best.
What am I having trouble with:
My problem: I have Cygwin and then want to follow these instructions  but cannot understand them. I opened up the Windows command prompt and simply put in make but it says `'make' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.`
If info is necessary, I don't have a init.vim file made and don't know how or where to put it.
I would appreciate it if anyone could help me with what I am trying to figure out. it's bugging me that I can't figure this out and I want to experience what everyone is clamoring about online. I want to be able to code fast and efficiently and I've already spent a lot of time trying to get Neovim set up, I might as well finish setting it up. Thank you for reading. Have a nice day!

Wow, nice exploration so far.
That research and curiosity will help on your vim journey.
If I am reading this right you are trying to build luajit from source.
This is not necessary as neovim includes luajit.
You mentioned you use scoop so I'd recommend installing neovim like this
scoop install neovim

That's it. It's simple to get a working neovim that includes luajit.
I install neovim this way and it works great. I use wezterm and install that from scoop as well.
I recommend taking some time to learn vim basics. Decide for yourself if you like it or not.
